# Rust: How to implement Command pattern with Dependent Components

Tags: design-patterns, rust

### Problem

I need to deploy a handful of services to an server environment. The services have dependent relationships (directed acyclic graph). For example, ServiceB relies on ServiceA to be deployed first and then ServiceB needs to configure ServiceA (e.g. MyWebService is dependent on Nginx to be deployed beforehand for its reverse proxy needs)

### Attempted Solutions

#### Attempt #1

I tried to implement this with [Command pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern), using `Vec`, `trait objects` similar to [what Rust book described](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch17-02-trait-objects.html):

([Link to Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=129eca1955ed3db4e963a236cf4d7db2))

```rust
trait Service {
    fn deploy(&self){}
}

struct ServiceA {}
impl Service for ServiceA {}

struct ServiceB<'a> {
    dep: &'a ServiceA,
}
impl<'a> Service for ServiceB<'a> {}

struct Environment {
    services: Vec<Box<dyn Service>>
}
impl Environment {
    fn deploy(&self) {
        for service in &self.services {
            service.deploy();
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let service_a = Box::new(ServiceA {});
    let service_b = Box::new(ServiceB { dep: &service_a });
    let environment = Environment {
        services: vec!(service_a, service_b)
    };
    environment.deploy();
}
```

This results in compile errors:

```
error[E0597]: `service_a` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:26:45
   |
26 |     let service_b = Box::new(ServiceB { dep: &service_a });
   |                                             ^^^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
27 |     let environment = Environment {
28 |         services: vec!(service_a, service_b)
   |                                   -------- cast requires that `service_a` is borrowed for `'static`
...
31 | }
   | - `service_a` dropped here while still borrowed

error[E0505]: cannot move out of `service_a` because it is borrowed
  --> src/main.rs:28:24
   |
26 |     let service_b = Box::new(ServiceB { dep: &service_a });
   |                                              --------- borrow of `service_a` occurs here
27 |     let environment = Environment {
28 |         services: vec!(service_a, service_b)
   |                        ^^^^^^^^  -------- cast requires that `service_a` is borrowed for `'static`
   |                        |
   |                        move out of `service_a` occurs here
```

#### Attempt #2

I added `Rc` for shared ownership:

([Link to Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f92ae227168fce295b1f2a1812d16102))

```rust
use std::rc::Rc;

trait Service {
    fn deploy(&self){}
}

struct ServiceA {}
impl Service for ServiceA {}

struct ServiceB<'a> {
    dep: &'a ServiceA,
}
impl<'a> Service for ServiceB<'a> {}

struct Environment {
    services: Vec<Rc<Box<dyn Service>>>
}
impl Environment {
    fn deploy(&self) {
        for service in &self.services {
            service.deploy();
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let service_a = Rc::new(Box::new(ServiceA {}));
    let service_b = Rc::new(Box::new(ServiceB { dep: &service_a }));
    let environment = Environment {
        services: vec!(Rc::clone(&service_a), Rc::clone(&service_b))
    };
    environment.deploy();
}
```

Now the errors become:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:30:34
   |
30 |         services: vec!(Rc::clone(&service_a), Rc::clone(&service_b))
   |                                  ^^^^^^^^^^ expected trait object `dyn Service`, found struct `ServiceA`
   |
   = note: expected reference `&Rc<Box<dyn Service>>`
              found reference `&Rc<Box<ServiceA>>`

error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:30:57
   |
30 |         services: vec!(Rc::clone(&service_a), Rc::clone(&service_b))
   |                                                         ^^^^^^^^^^ expected trait object `dyn Service`, found struct `ServiceB`
   |
   = note: expected reference `&Rc<Box<dyn Service>>`
              found reference `&Rc<Box<ServiceB<'_>>>`
```

Can you help shed some light on the errors? Any idea on better implementation / pattern to solve the problem? Thanks!

Comment: As a general observation, trying to apply OOP patterns to a non-OOP language is likely fraught with pain and difficulty.

Comment: @eggyal Thanks for the comment! Any suggestion on which pattern I should use to solve this problem?

Comment: I don't think that in your example, the `deploy` methods actually get called in the correct order. You *construct* them in the correct order, but that doesn't translate to the *deploy* order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intuition to use `Rc` in this situation is correct. Your use of `Box`, however, is not.

`Box` and `Rc` are almost identical. Both put a value on the heap, the difference is ownership and mutability:

- `Box` provides **mutable** access to a heap value for **one** owner.
- `Rc` provides **immutable** access to a heap value for **multiple** owners.

Therefore `Rc<Box<>>` doesn't make much sense, just use `Rc<>` instead.

Second, I don't think `ServiceB` should hold a reference to `ServiceA`. If you have an `Rc`, use it. Lifetime management will become very complicated/impossible in this scenario. `Rc` avoids lifetime management by refcounting.

Here you go:

```rust
use std::rc::Rc;

trait Service {
    fn deploy(&self) {}
}

struct ServiceA {}
impl Service for ServiceA {}

struct ServiceB {
    dep: Rc<ServiceA>,
}
impl Service for ServiceB {}

struct Environment {
    services: Vec<Rc<dyn Service>>,
}
impl Environment {
    fn deploy(&self) {
        for service in &self.services {
            service.deploy();
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let service_a = Rc::new(ServiceA {});
    let service_b = Rc::new(ServiceB {
        dep: service_a.clone(),
    });
    let environment = Environment {
        services: vec![service_a, service_b],
    };
    environment.deploy();
}
```

---

### Further remarks

All your member functions are `&self`, meaning, imutable. Which is good in this case, because immutable references is all that an `Rc` can offer. But if inevitably run into the problem that you do need to mutate a Service, read about [`interior mutability`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-05-interior-mutability.html), `Cell` and `RefCell`. And if you are going to wards multi-threading, `Arc` and `Mutex`.

You might, however, run into further problems with the `dyn Service` later on. `Rc<ServiceA>` is castable to `Rc<dyn Service>`. This does not, however, apply to `Rc<RefCell<ServiceA>>` and `Rc<RefCell<dyn Service>>`. A solution would be to keep all `Service` structs completely immutable and have an interior mutable object inside them.

Comment: Thank you! It works and also thanks for tips on casting problem of `Rc<RefCell<ServiceA>>`